# How to force push code from Visual Studio 2019 to GIt

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I have created a new Visual Studio 2019 project.

When trying to push it to a Git Repo in Azure Dev Ops I get the below error

Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: rejected Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes  before pushing again.
Failed to push the branch to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.

How can I resolve this? Is there a way to force the push?

Comment: It sounds like you first need a *pull* to get the latest changes, and probably a merge

Comment: I did try this, but it made no difference, there is no changes to fetch.

Comment: It appears you are having a conflict in case you have uncommitted changes. Try resolving the conflict first then do a `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`(in case `pull.rebase` returns `false` after running `git config --list` or `git config --system --list`)

Comment: Can you do this through Visual Studio? As I do not have the Git command line installed. Or maybe I do have it installed but I cannot find it and do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your error message,  the remote branch has some changes after your clone the repo in Visual Studio.

To solve this issue, you could try the following two methods:

In Visual studio, when the see the error message, you could see the `Pull/Pull and Push` option in the pop-ups.

[image]

Or in the `sync tab`

[image]

2.Command Line scripts: Since you could run push changes in Visual stduio, the git has been installed already.

```
cd repo path

git pull
```

If you couldn't see it, you could run the following commands in cmd:

[image]

**Update1:**

You could run the following git command in your repo file path:

```
cd repo path

git pull
git add --all
git commit -m "first commit of my code"

git push -f origin master
```

When you run the git pull, you could check if it returns the message: `Already up to date`.

If yes, you could run the git push command to directly push the changes to Azure Repo.

Comment: I have done a pull from the origin many times, using visual studio user interface and unfortunately it has not resolved the issue.

Comment: In your case, you could try to use git command in your CMD to push the changes to Azure Repo. Please refer to my update 1

Comment: The command-line instructions worked. I just want to point out I had trouble following the instructions because I got the following error when typing "git" into the command prompt.

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

To work around this I entered the full path to git, which is installed with Visual Studio 2019 at D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd\git.exe